# Automation of downloading NiFi flows and uploading them to another cluster

Tags: python, java, bigdata, apache-nifi

I am relatively new to NiFi and I was wondering if it is possible to automate the process of downloading some NiFi templates and then uploading them to another cluster.

More precisely, I created a local flow, which I downloaded and uploaded to a server where it runs continuously. I would like to work on the local flow, and when I make changes, to download and upload automatically on the flow running on the server.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Thanks:)

I did everything manually, I wish it could be automated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could take a look at NiFi Registry, it could help you solve the issue. Also, to automate the process there are API support provided which can be used to automate the update on the Main cluster once your development is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Calin

Everything you describe is possible programatically using the NIFI API.

Some things to consider:

1. The nifi api is available from command line or within a nifi flow
   (invokeHttp). So you can make a nifi flow that does this.  [DOCS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html)
2. Check out [Nifi Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html) as a mechanism to version and move flows between enviornments.
3. Check out JSON Flow Definition Files vs NiFi XML Templates (these are going away) [DOCS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html)
4. Check out [this flow](https://github.com/cldr-steven-matison/NiFi-Templates/blob/main/NiFi_Template_XML_to_Flow_Definition_JSON.json) I built that demos how to use the API within a nifi flow itself.  This particular flow is used to convert XML to JSON, but it has the framework needed to execute the api calls within nifi itself.